# @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram-bot

не получается написать эхо бота выдает ошибку,сам бот не отвечает

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1345484602:AAGVrxVGKduZBKzBO-e4iDCo79kE1jzQjpE")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    # bot.reply_to("message, message_text")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id , message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: ваш код абсолютно рабочий. и спасибо за токен)

Comment: но почему он не работает ?

Comment: у меня ваш код, скопированный, со сменой токена на свой - отрабатывает без ошибок: эхо бот. где у вас хэндлер находится?

Comment: хэндлер это что ?

Comment: `@bot.message_handler`

Comment: ну так он в коде ,а его еще куда нужно вставлять ?

Comment: я работал в intelig idea и у меня не запускался код,попробывал в visual studia и получилось